# iframe - location - same origin policy

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

As I was always believing, iframe properties (if the iframe is loaded from another origin) can not be get but set.
I tried some little testcases, but it seems that I can always get the properties.
Am I doing something wrong in setting up the example?

```
<iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.org" id="iframe"></iframe>

<script>

    try {
        alert(document.getElementById("iframe").src);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }

</script>
```

The above example alerts the correct location in my tests.

Regards

Comment: Yes, of course, it would! All that code is doing is alerting the source attribute of the `iframe` tag *on your page*!

Comment: so what? the location attribute is protected but the src is not? or how is this working?

Comment: You're missing the point.  There is a distinction to be made between `iframe` *content* and `iframe` *tag*.

Answer (score 2):

You are not accessing some content elements/properties of a contained document. You are just getting the `src` attribute of the `iframe` that is set by the outer document. Just try this:

```
iframeElement.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```